# Error importing SVG in react-redux MERN application

Tags: node.js, svg, reactjs, webpack, mern

I need to load an .svg file into a react component in a MERN boilerplate project.
I configured the webpack url-loader with this entry in the **webpack.config.dev.js**:

```
{
 test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.otf$|\.ttf$/i,
 loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
}
```

and i attempt to access to the resource in the component with:

```
import logo from '../../../../assets/logo_h.svg'
```

but i got this error launching the **npm start**

```
SyntaxError: : Unexpected token (1:1)
> 1 | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    |  ^
```

Comment: Is there any other loaders also load `.svg`? ex: `babel-loader`

Comment: i have configured the babel loader for jsx files:  `{
        test: /\.jsx*$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /.+\.config.js/],
        loader: 'babel',
      }`

Comment: i have not other loader for .svg files

Comment: Are you using webpack for server-side rendering?

Comment: Yes i have a webpack.config.server.js file with this entry: `,
      {
        test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$/i,
        loader: 'null-loader',
      },`

Comment: They all look good. It might be other problem. Do you mind to provide a small repo to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `<?xml ...` at the top of the SVG. It isn't needed to render the SVG and often throws errors in webpack when trying to parse.